# How to boil 40ml of water using a solar panel of 15v and 1amp?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, temperature

I am making an application to use in third world countries where there is unlimited sunshine
I need to boile a very small amount of water, up to 40ml, using a solar panel that generates 15v and up to 1 amp
If possible what resistor ahould I use and any information on how to build this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For every solar panel there is a particular combination of current and voltage that will maximize power output.  You can either look at the datasheet for the panel to find those values. Or you can test the panel with different resistors of known value and create your own graph like the one below. Once you know the current and voltage you need you can calculate the resistance of the load you need with Ohn's Law:$R=V/I$

[image]